# What's the meaning of three dots in parameter declaration?

Tags: java, parameters, declaration

What do the three dots after "Object" mean in this parameter declaration:

```
public static int queryCount (
    Connection conn, String whereClause,
    Object ... params)
    throws Exception
```

In what way does it differ from the parameter declaration `Object params` ?

Comment: This notation is called `varargs`.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html

Comment: @Luiggi: You are completely right, I saw it later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature was introduced in Java to hide the process of using Arrays as parameters, in form of `varargs`.
As the [documentation states](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html), the process is stil same but complexity has been reduced.

Please note following points:

- This allows for entering an array or sequence of type specified.
- This form must be used at last in parameters list.
- This is **not** available in older version, so be careful if you plan to deploy to older versions of Java

Answer (score 1):

Three dots mean that there method can get as parameters as much argument of type Object as it likes. Reading more about "varargs" arguments could be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In short, it's a syntactic sugar for array with restriction that this should be the last parameter in arguments list.

e.g. it's totally legal to declare main method as follows

`public static void main(String... args) {}`

And another feature of this, this argument is optional, but you still will get an empty array as a value of argument.